# What is a Cartesian form for the parametric $(x,y)=\left(\sin(t)\cosh(t),\cos(t)\sinh(t)\right)$?

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

What is a Cartesian form for the parametric $$(x,y)=\left(\sin(t)\cosh(t),\cos(t)\sinh(t)\right)$$ Does a Cartesian form exist?

I tried doing it by solving for t and substituting, but I don't believe it is possible to solve for t in this case. Do you have any other possible methods?

Comment: $x^2+y^2=1$....

Comment: That's for $(x, y) = (\sin(t), \cos(t))$ but the extra factors of $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ will make it more complicated.

Comment: It may or may not be useful, but you can also write this as a parameterized curve $$z=\sin(1+i)t$$ So as the control point moves along the diagonal in the parameter plane, the image point traces out the specified curve under the action of the complex sine function (assuming I didn't goof up the computation).

Comment: Thats right, I actually came from there. I had that originally and I was trying to find a cartesian form for it, but I found the parametric first.

Comment: Also just wondering is there a special name for the type of spiral the curve traces?

Comment: Don't know about specific names, but curves of this form are generally what I would consider exponential spirals